# Iterating through DataFrame with columns named after an array of numbers

Tags: python, pandas

so I have the following code:

```
rang=np.linspace((0.8*Sclose), (1.2*Sclose), 100)
ts=[6, 5, 10, 15]
df=pd.DataFrame(index=rang, columns=list(ts))
```

which gives:

```
In[138]: df.head()
Out[138]: 
           6.0  5.0  10.0 15.0
209.040000  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
210.095758  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
211.151515  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
212.207273  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
213.263030  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

which is what I want. What I want to do next is fill in the columns by parsing the column name and the index at that point to a method which will return a value.

```
def method1(x, y): 
    return (x+y), (x*y)

for x, y in list(ts), range(len(df.index)):
     df[x][y]=method1(x, df.index[y])[0]
```

but that's not working. Also note that the length and values in ts will vary most times I run the code so it needs to be flexible enough to be able to handle that. Hence why I tried the loop that I did.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] inlcuding expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

```
In [294]: def method1(x, y):
     ...:     return x + 10*y
     ...:

In [295]: from itertools import product

In [296]: data = np.array([method1(x, y) for x,y in product(df.index, df.columns)]) \
                   .reshape(df.shape)

In [297]: pd.DataFrame(data, df.index, df.columns)
Out[297]:
                  6.0         5.0         10.0        15.0
209.040000  269.040000  259.040000  309.040000  359.040000
210.095758  270.095758  260.095758  310.095758  360.095758
211.151515  271.151515  261.151515  311.151515  361.151515
212.207273  272.207273  262.207273  312.207273  362.207273
213.263030  273.263030  263.263030  313.263030  363.263030
```

---

**Old answer:**

Use [np.add.outer()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html).

Demo:

```
In [257]: df
Out[257]:
            6.0   5.0   10.0  15.0
209.040000   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
210.095758   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
211.151515   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
212.207273   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
213.263030   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN

In [258]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.add.outer(df.index, df.columns), df.index, df.columns)

In [259]: df
Out[259]:
                  6.0         5.0         10.0        15.0
209.040000  215.040000  214.040000  219.040000  224.040000
210.095758  216.095758  215.095758  220.095758  225.095758
211.151515  217.151515  216.151515  221.151515  226.151515
212.207273  218.207273  217.207273  222.207273  227.207273
213.263030  219.263030  218.263030  223.263030  228.263030
```

NOTE: this solution assumes that both `df.index` and `df.columns` are of numeric dtypes. If it's not the case, then convert them to numeric dtypes beforehand.

Comment: Sorry I should've clarified: I don't actually just want to add the two of them. My actual version of method1 is a bit more complex than the example I used. Whilst your solution here would work well if I wanted to add the outer parts, I actually want to parse the two numbers to a function and receive the output of that.

Comment: @bigboat, i've updated my answer  - now it can use a generic function - please check...

Comment: perfect. You're a legend